# Looking to find a way to determine replicated objects from subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am trying to create a process to script out items that have been added to subscriber databases in transactional or snapshot replication - sometimes we find users have added a view or proc to a database for example.

I know that from the publisher end you can check to see if an object "is Published" but is there something comparable from the Subscriber end - something like an "is subscribed"?

If we have to script out every single object we can, but it would be much less time consuming if I could filter out all of the objects from the publication.

Poking around I don't see such a thing

Comment: [Might check this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4744671/847990)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method but with a little modification, I'm sure you could get what you need:

```
SELECT dest_table AS TableName 
FROM LinkedServer.PubDB.dbo.sysarticles
WHERE pubid = 1 --(this may vary - you have to get the pubid)
```

If from subscriber, you could create a linked server and run it on the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

On the subscriber database you can run this.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [SubscribeDBName].[dbo].[MSreplication_objects]
```